# Is there a way to use scrollTo to hide url bar with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need manipulate url-bar in `Chrome mobile` to make it hide or appear. But I found that `scrollTo` do not work with react-router. Maybe there is a workaround to manipulate url-bar?

Comment: This is something native for browser, you can't manipulate this.

Comment: in the chrome or any other browser, you can't, it is part of browser, but you can use `PWA`, it is a type of application software delivered through the web, in another word, it makes the app like a native mobile app whenever user adds the website to home screen, so there is no URL bar in that, read more about `PWA` https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

Comment: @poPaTheGuru yeah, but generally with `scrollTo` you can manipulate this, just not using react-router. It is kind of a hack, but... The thing is I have a fullscreen scrolling div in my app which user opens. And the thing is: if the url bar was open, it will be till you scroll to the very end. And if not - you will not see it also. Which is an even bigger disadvantage.

Comment: @yahyaparvar yeah, thanks :) but not every user will install my PWA.